# How to perform stemming and lemmatization in R?

Tags: r, stemming, lemmatization

I am processing text data which have string like given below

> "significant step towards large scale hydrogen production iisc team
>   collaboration jncasr researcher develop low cost catalyst speed split
>   water generate hydrogen gas"

In order to get correct form of words in text...stemming or lemmatization is to be done. I am doing this, but its not giving the desired output

```
stemDocument(p[1], language = "english")
```

> [1] "signific step toward larg scale hydrogen product iisc team
>   collabor jncasr research develop low cost catalyst speed split water
>   generat hydrogen gas"

```
lemmatize_strings(p[1], dictionary = lexicon::hash_lemmas)
```

> [1] "significant step towards large scale hydrogen production iisc
>   team collaboration jncasr researcher develop low cost catalyst speed
>   split water generate hydrogen gas"

How to get the output like this

> significant step toward large scale hydrogen produce iisc team
>   collaborate jncasr research develop low cost catalyst speed split
>   water generate hydrogen gas

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is probably worth giving the package that you are using. To do what you wish you could do the following with the following two packages

```
library(udpipe)

# This takes a minute to download the english dictionary
x <- udpipe(x = "significant step towards large scale hydrogen production iisc team 
            collaboration jncasr researcher develop low cost catalyst 
            speed split water generate hydrogen gas",
            object = "english")
```

This will give you all kinds of information for your analysis, including the token, the lemma, etc. You can do a lot with this.

```
 x$lemma
 [1] "significant"   "step"          "towards"       "large"         "scale"         "hydrogen"      "production"   
 [8] "iisc"          "team"          "collaboration" "jncasr"        "researcher"    "develop"       "low"          
[15] "cost"          "catalyst"      "speed"         "split"         "water"         "generate"      "hydrogen"     
[22] "gas"
```

To stem the word you could use the `tm` package. If you want to stem the lemmas you have them:

```
library(tm)
tm::stemDocument(x$lemma)
```

Which will give you the following:

```
[1] "signific" "step"     "toward"   "larg"     "scale"    "hydrogen" "product"  "iisc"     "team"     "collabor"
[11] "jncasr"   "research" "develop"  "low"      "cost"     "catalyst" "speed"    "split"    "water"    "generat" 
[21] "hydrogen" "gas"
```